# Fetch user Profile Info Facebook Using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

trying Fetch User profile Data But I got Only User id,link,name,first_name,last_name,email and gender .Remaining values are undefined.But according to facebook javascript sdk i have passed fields so it should have to provide me all fields which i have required .

```
 FB.api('/me', {fields: 'id,link,name,first_name,last_name,email,birthday,education,gender,hometown,location,religion,relationship_status,work'},function(response) {
                console.log(response);

          var str="<b>Name</b> : "+response.name+"<br>";
              str="<b>First Name</b> : "+response.first_name+"<br>";
              str="<b>Last Name</b> : "+response.last_name+"<br>";
              str +="<b>Link: </b>"+response.link+"<br>";
              str +="<b>Username:</b> "+response.location.name+"<br>";
              str +="<b>id: </b>"+response.id+"<br>";
              str +="<b>Email:</b> "+response.email+"<br>";
              str +="<input type='button' value='Get Photo' onclick='getPhoto();'/>";
              str +="<input type='button' value='Logout' onclick='Logout();'/>";
              document.getElementById("status").innerHTML=str;

        });
```

console result :

```
email
"hassanali5420@yahoo.com"
first_name
"Hassan"
gender
"male"
id
"1517510821901697"
last_name
"ALi"
link
"https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1517510821901697/"
name
"Hassan ALi"
```

Comment: Where’s the part where you ask for the permissions necessary to access this data?

Comment: I have the Whole Permissions that's why i getting these details .Notice I have logged in and I have Already all permissions from users.

Comment: Then the user most likely does not have the information you request set in their profile. (Or you do not really have all the permissions you think you do – double check, f.e. by debugging your access token or a call for `/me/permissions`.)

Comment: Yeah i do thinks its the issue related to Permissions ...